# count number of occurrences per hour, day, and week from a timestamp in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have trouble writing logic using pyspark.
I am looking to add a column to the existing data frame by calculating the number of occurrences on a given day based on `user_id`.

Example dataframe:

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 9:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:20:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 9:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 9:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 9:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 9:30:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 9:00:00 |

i am looking for output something like below

| user_id | timestamp | perday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 9:00:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:20:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 9:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 9:00:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 9:30:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 9:00:00 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can count with window function:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('perday', f.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy(df.user_id, f.to_date(df.timestamp)))).show()
+-------+-------------------+------+
|user_id|          timestamp|perday|
+-------+-------------------+------+
|      2| 2021-01-02 9:00:00|     2|
|      2| 2021-01-02 9:30:00|     2|
|      1|2021-01-02 10:00:00|     1|
|      1| 2021-01-01 9:00:00|     3|
|      1|2021-01-01 10:20:00|     3|
|      1|2021-01-01 18:00:00|     3|
|      2| 2021-01-01 9:00:00|     1|
|      1| 2021-01-03 9:00:00|     1|
+-------+-------------------+------+
```